# Неправильная дата GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, android, дата, calendar

Есть кусок кода:

```
private void changeCalendarDay(int daysCount,int field){
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.set(year,month,day);
    calendar.add(field,daysCount);
    year = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DATE);
}
```

Этот метод вызывается по нажатию на кнопку вот код вызова:

```
addDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        changeCalendarDay(1,GregorianCalendar.DATE);
        updateDateEditText();
    }
});
```

Проблема в том, что когда я на неё нажимаю, то всё работает до 30.08.2017 числа, если нажать на кнопку ещё раз, то вместо 31.08.2017 дата меняется на 01.09.2017. И такая проблема с другими месяцами...  Что я делаю не так?

Вывод даты производится методом `updateDateEditText()`:

```
private void updateDateEditText(){
    if(month<10) {
        currentDateEditText.setText(day+".0"+month+"."+year);
    } else {
        currentDateEditText.setText(day+"."+month+"."+year);
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите как выводите дату

Comment: Вывожу её в EditText, беру значения из переменных year,month, day. Сейчас добавлю кусок кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Месяцы (поле [`Calendar.MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)) нумеруются с нуля. Соответственно, 0 — это январь, а 8 — сентябрь.

Из документации:

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. **The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0**; ..

Для преобразования даты в строку в заданном формате проще использовать [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
 String text = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо Вам огромное) Я об этом даже не подумал)

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае попробуйте воспользоваться SimpleDateFormat, он на много удобен:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class DateTest
{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DateTest.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out
                .println(
                        new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
                        .format(
                                changeCalendarDay(5, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                        )
                );
    }

    private static Date changeCalendarDay(int daysCount, int field)
    {
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.set(2017, 10, 10);
        calendar.add(field, daysCount);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, да, так будет лучше)